# Por que tenho que atribuir o valor do método prepare para a uma variável para só depois instanciar o execute? no pdo

Tags: php, pdo

Ex:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM BD");
$stmt->execute();
```

Por que não funciona se eu instanciar o método execute da mesma instância? já que o valor já foi passado para o método prepare? ex:

```
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM DB");
$db->execute();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `$db` que é seu variável da classe [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) tem o método [prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), que é responsável em preparar um comando de execução ([SQL](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql)) e que o mesmo retorna um [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) e nele tem o método execute, ou seja, `$db` não possui esse método `execute` mas, possui um método que retornar um [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) que tem o execute.

No `$db` você pode utilizar diretamente o [PDO::query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php), que também retornar um [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) já executado sendo esse com retorno de dados e [PDO::exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php), que executa comandos de Insert, Update e Delete que retornar a quantidade de linhas afetadas.

```
//select
$db->query("SELECT * FROM BD");
```

---

```
//insert, update e delete
$rowsafetados = $db->exec("INSERT INTO BD ...");
```

#### Porque isso tudo acontece?

Há separação de responsabilidade entras as classes ([POO](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos)) e cada classe tem sua própria responsabilidade, `$db` conexão e métodos rápido, e PDOStatement que usa a `$db` como conexão para seus métodos.

Comment: opcionalmente ele pode encadear as chamadas `$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM BD")->execute();`

Comment: até vai funcionar, mas, o problema que ai não vai ser retornado um PDOStatement, ele vai retornar um `bool` como descrito no site PHP.net (http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.execute.php), talvez para alguns casos funcione bem mas, o melhor é utilizar um PDOStatement

Comment: tem razão, deveria ser `fetch` ou `fetchAll`.

Answer (score 2):

Porque `$db` é uma instância da classe [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) e ela representa uma **conexão** com o banco de dados. Já `$stmt` por sua vez é um instância da classe [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), que em termos simples representa uma única **query**.

Basta pensar um pouco: `$db` não pode ser **executada** porque ela é uma conexão, executar uma conexão seria o ato de conectar-se, mas você já está conectado. Então `$stmt` representa uma **query**, e é ela quem você **executa**.

Ainda sim a classe [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) possui uma função [`PDO::exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.exec.php) que permite você realizar queries rapidamente, porém sem a possibilidade de buscar resultados, tendo como retorno apenas a quantidade de linhas modificadas.